# Android Kotlin what is Promise?

Tags: android, kotlin

I work on Android (Kotlin) with a WebView  who load some Page and i have interection with this page with
@JavascriptInterface

My client write some function i had to implement, for exemple :

```
 @JavascriptInterface
    fun fileExists(path: String): Promise<Boolean>? {
        return null
    }
```

But class Promise is not found, and I don't know what is it and which library I need to use.

His only answer is "Look how Cordova transforme Promise into Java Object"

Maybe someone can help me or just give some start of information, now I even don't know direction

I have try this 2
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"

but not Pormise Object inside.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Promise** as a pattern is well known in `JS` world, but it's not so popular among `Android` folks, maybe because of the fact that we have a very powerful `RxJava` library. But what if you need `RxJava` just for a single value response (Single) such as single network request and couple transformation operation like `flatMap` and `map`. If this is the case then you should consider `Promise` pattern that works well for single value response.

**Example use of `Promise`:**

```
fun postItem(item: Item) {
    preparePostAsync() 
        .thenCompose { token -> 
            submitPostAsync(token, item)
        }
        .thenAccept { post -> 
            processPost(post)
        }

}

fun preparePostAsync(): Promise<Token> {
    // makes request an returns a promise that is completed later
    return promise 
}
```

Comment: My problem is class "Promise" not exist. Which library i need to add to have it ?